# C# extension methods for ASP.NET or C# in general (.Net 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, extension-methods

I'm searching for some extension methods that helps programming in ASP.NET. Some functions to work on controls, validators, AJAX or programing in C# in general.
It could be methods library or your own methods.

Do you know any source of those methods (other than CodePlex - that is good source of generic extensions) especially for ASP.NET?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: you are asking us to post our common extension methods that have been developed? really?

Comment: I'm searching for libraries with common methods or some methods that you created and want to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[extension method - from CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=extension%20method&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=1)

Comment: Thanks, that is good source of generic C# extensions methods. But I found only few extensions to ASP.NET (there are some in http://dnpextensions.codeplex.com/). Maybe there is other place where I can find extensions to ASP.NET?